# Restore all Notes from iCloud

Tags: restore

I deleted numerous Notes from my phone that I want to get back from iCloud.  My phone has not updated to iCloud so the Notes are still good on the cloud.  How do I get all files from cloud back onto phone

Answer (score 2):

First, access the notes in iCloud and copy their contents, just in case. Second, one solution that should work is to edit each of the notes slightly, giving them something that happened to them more recently than when you deleted the from your phone. Third, on to your iPhone, disable Notes from the iClouds portion of Settings which should make them local. Go online, turn the Notes syncing back on, and it should get them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to go to [icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/), log in with your iCloud Apple ID, and click the "Notes" app icon. All of your notes *should* be there for you to access.

Obviously if you have had an internet connection it may have already synced those changes (deletions) and if that's the case your notes will be permanently lost.

Go ahead and email the deleted notes to yourself, or, create new notes and copy the deleted ones in there.

And certainly don't connect your iPhone to the internet in the mean time.